# firebase get downloadTokens from putString()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code for uploading image to fire storage:

```
myRef.putString(baseurl,'data_url').then(snapshot=>{
  console.log(snapshot)
}
```

I can't find anything related to downloadTokens in `snapshot`.
Is it possible to get the downloadTokens for the uploaded image from the snapshot?
Here is what I found in the network after triggering the `putString()` method:

[image]

Is there a `downloadTokens` property in the snapshot returned by putString()?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "here is what I found in the network"?  What did you do to get that screenshot?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: It still looks the same to me, and there's no record of chance since I edited the tags.

Comment: I don't think the data you're looking for is available in the API.  But I'm still curious what exactly you mean by "here is what I found in the network".

Comment: If you fire putString() and open chrome - developer tool - network, you will see something similar to the screenshot